# ttys no longer show release version after 16.04 Update (from 14.04.4)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, tty

On Ubuntu 14.04.4 (and previous), there was a message at the top of each tty (1-6) that said

> `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS $HOST tty1` #or `tty2` etc.
>
> `$HOST login:`

I upgraded to 16.04 (with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`).

**During** the upgrade, I loaded tty3, and it said

> `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS $HOST tty3`
>
> `$HOST login`

However, after the upgrade, all the ttys said was

> `$HOST login:`

Without the Ubuntu version or the tty number.

---

Is this intended for 16.04? If so, is there a way to change it back to showing the version? (like with `getty` configs or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message comes from the file `/etc/issue` and/or `/etc/issue.net`.

I would imagine that you either lost these files or they are not readable by root (?!?) or they do not get printed anymore.

The files should automatically have been updated.

It would be set to the output of `lsb_release -d` or something of the sort.

If that does not work for you, you could create a script under `/etc/profile.d/...` and put:

```
lsb_release -a
```

In that script. That being said, the motd (Message of the Day) should be displayed when you log in and that should already include all the necessary information about the machine.

Comment: Thank you! Writing `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS \n \l` to `/etc/issue` brought back the default message.